# can't import pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to import Pandas in Python termination, but it won't take the next step unless I press CTRL C to stop the process. If I press the CTRL C after a little while (about 2 seconds), the pandas will be imported successfully. If the time is too short, it will show the keyboard interrupt exception. It looks like Pandas does import but something goes wrong after that. I have to press CTRL C to import Pandas, and that's too awful. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Any suggestion will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: It is very difficult to answer this question without your code.  Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Pandas is not properly installed (or not installed at all) on your local machine.

I've never installed Pandas as a standalone library.

What I would recommend however, is installing the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) distribution for Python 2 or 3. This encapsulates Pandas as well as other libraries (Scipy, Numpy, Matplotlib) that relies on.

Installing Anaconda seamlessly resolves dependency problems and generally guarantees a stable environment.

Once everything ix installed you can fire up a terminal, launch python, ipython or jupyter and import pandas.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, man. problem solved! It is the matplotlib that calls a function in tempfile.py, temping to create a file in a directory where it has no permission to do, which causes the error.